# How to decorate a parent class and make child classes use it? python

Tags: python, python-decorators

What I want is to create a class decorator to decorate a class and works on subclasses too.

Imagine this class:

```
class CustomBaseTest(TransactionTestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def more_custom_helpers(self):
        ...
```

and the real Test:

```
class FooTest(CustomBaseTest):
    def decorate_this_foo_is_ok(self):
        ....

    def decorate_this_fails(self):
        ...
```

what I want is to use a decorator in `CustomBaseTest` that finds all methods that starts with 'decoratte_this_' and execute custom code after and before. I already have the decorator, something like this:

```
def class_decorator(klass):
    is_method_test = lambda m: not m.startswith('_') and m.startswith('decorate_this_') and isinstance(getattr(klass, m), MethodType)
    test_methods = filter(is_method_test, dir(klass))

    for method_name in test_methods:
        class_method = getattr(klass, method_name)

        def helper(mname, method):
            @wraps(method)
            ... some logic here
            retval = method(*a, **kw)
            ... more logic here
            return retval
        return wrapper

        fn = MethodType(helper(method_name, class_method), None, klass)
        setattr(klass, method_name, fn)
    return klass
```

do you know if is possible to do that? and how?

thanks!!!

Comment: 1) Try setting the `__metaclass__` attribute of the class. 2) Modify the base class's `__new__` method.

Comment: Class decorators only apply to the actual class they decorate.  As Joel Cornett says, you could use a metaclass.  Google around for info on how to use metaclasses.

Comment: __metaclass__ is the way to go!!! thanks guys!!! I solved my problem!!!! :)

Comment: @pahko, you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Markku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275418/markku-k) and [@BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427416/brenbarn).

Here is the solution.

First we have a simple decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
def my_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # do more stuff
        return retval
    return wrapper
```

And the metaclass:

```
class ProfileMetaByClass(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for method_name, method in dct.items():
            if method_name.startswith('decorate_this_'):
                setattr(cls, method_name, my_decorator(method))
        type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

And that worked for me!